# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext can't find xml file

Tags: spring, maven, applicationcontext

[image]

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springTest/BeanTest.xml");
```

throw file not found exception. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you do "classpath*:springTest/BeanText.xml"?

Comment: Where is the code which is creating the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`? If that is in a class in `src/main/resources` it won't be able to see the files in `src/test`.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the BeanTest.xml in the src/main/resources directory instead of test directory and try

Comment: I found myself very stupid. It is not file not found exception. It is about the bean....sorry guys.